# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a simple array of UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, arrays, memory, uiimageview

What is wrong with this code?

in the interface:

```
NSArray *myImages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myImages;
```

implementation:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]],
                [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]],        
                [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]],
                nil];
self.myImages = array;
[array release];
```

If I log myImages right after initializing it, it correctly logs the array of UIImageViews. However, later in the app, when I try to access self.myImages from a different method, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It is getting retained in the interface. What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not release `array`. Using `arrayWithObjects:`, it will return an autoreleased object. In a sense, you are releasing it twice. An alternative is:

```
[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:...]
```

Then you can release `array`.

See Apple's memory management article:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB

Answer (score 2):

arrayWithObjects is a convenience method and returns an autoreleased object, so remove the

```
[array release];
```

Plus you leak memory by doing this :

```
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]]
```

Because this time the imageView isn't released.

Answer (score 1):

arrayWithObjects returns an autoreleased object, you're over releasing it. See here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH